# Flutter app crashes after reaching home screen after building the release apk

Tags: flutter, crash

Am using physical device and when i run the app directly from android studio in debugging mode it works without any crashes after i validate the app i build the apk release and it gets built without any problems but when i try the app on the physical device it works like following :

Splash screen => homescreen

and then few seconds in the home screen the app crashes with no error log at all without any reason.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons. I suggest to first try to get the device logs either with ADB/Android Studio or XCode and see if you can find a problem there.

It could be memory related, maybe you have some big memory leak or you work with images. You can implement a `WidgetsBindingObserver.didHaveMemoryPressure` in your root widget and add some logging there to figure out if you are using too much memory.

Without more information on the error it will practically impossible to figure out the source.

Comment: Note that the crash happens only in android

Comment: On Android it is easier to check the logs, try to figure out the exception in Android Studio Logcat and then we can go further.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option without guessing bug:

- Use Android logcat
- Configure a bug management tool like Sentry https://sentry.io/